# How to append a 2d array with a 1d array in VB?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, multidimensional-array, append

I'm having difficulties to find a way to add 1d array to a 2d array in VB. For example:

```
Dim arr(,) As Integer
arr = { {0, 1}, {2, 3}, {4, 5} }
arr{3} = {6, 7}
'Now arr should be = { {0, 1}, {2, 3}, {4, 5}, {6, 7} }
```

**Note that the code above is just a demonstration on what I want to achieve, it doesn't work.**

I have been trying things suggested on forum such as:

1. ReDim Preserve
2. Array.Resize
3. Making 2d loop to copy everysingle element to a new variable and add new element then ReDim it back to arr

All I tried, but they all doesn't seem to work. At the end of the day, I'm looking for a subroutine that could append an 2d array of unknown length for example:

```
Dim arr(,) As Integer
append(arr, {0, 1})
append(arr, {2, 3})
'Now arr should be = {{0, 1}, {2, 3}}
```

Comment: Some of you might be wondering, why I need this in a subroutine, at the end of the day. Because in my program, I will be needing to append a 2d array from different functions and modules.

Comment: It would appear you want a `List(Of Integer())`.

Comment: I have to this for a school project. The criteria of the project doesn't seem to allow me to use List as data structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `Redim Preserve` the array, but you cannot do that because it adds another column when you want another row. So you will have to define a new array and copy the data:

```
Public Sub Append2DRow(ByRef arr(,) As Integer, new_row(,) As Integer)
    Dim new_arr(,) As Integer
    ReDim new_arr(0 To UBound(arr, 1) + 1, 0 To 1)

    Array.Copy(arr, new_arr, arr.LongLength)

    new_arr(UBound(new_arr, 1), 0) = new_row(0, 0)
    new_arr(UBound(new_arr, 1), 1) = new_row(0, 1)

    arr = new_arr
End Sub

Public Sub Append1DRow(ByRef arr(,) As Integer, new_row() As Integer)
    Dim new_arr(,) As Integer
    ReDim new_arr(0 To UBound(arr, 1) + 1, 0 To 1)

    Array.Copy(arr, new_arr, arr.LongLength)

    new_arr(UBound(new_arr, 1), 0) = new_row(0)
    new_arr(UBound(new_arr, 1), 1) = new_row(1)

    arr = new_arr
End Sub
```

```
Dim arr(,) As Integer
arr = {{0, 1}, {2, 3}, {4, 5}}

Append2DRow(arr, {{6, 7}})
Append1DRow(arr, {6, 7})
```

You can avoid this problem by forcing yourself into having an array with two rows and variable number of columns, but then you won't be able to initialize it that easily and it will probably be more difficult to work with in general:

```
Public Sub Append2DRow(ByRef arr(,) As Integer, new_row(,) As Integer)
    ReDim Preserve arr(0 To 1, 0 To UBound(arr, 2) + 1)
    arr(0, UBound(arr, 2)) = new_row(0, 0)
    arr(1, UBound(arr, 2)) = new_row(0, 1)
End Sub

Public Sub Append1DRow(ByRef arr(,) As Integer, new_row() As Integer)
    ReDim Preserve arr(0 To 1, 0 To UBound(arr, 2) + 1)
    arr(0, UBound(arr, 2)) = new_row(0)
    arr(1, UBound(arr, 2)) = new_row(1)
End Sub
```

```
Dim arr(0 To 1, 0 To 2) As Integer
arr(0, 0) = 0 : arr(1, 0) = 1
arr(0, 1) = 2 : arr(1, 1) = 3
arr(0, 2) = 4 : arr(1, 2) = 5

Append2DRow(arr, {{6, 7}})
Append1DRow(arr, {6, 7})
```

However you should not use arrays for this to begin with. You should use lists:

```
Dim list = New List(Of Integer()) From {
    New Integer() {0, 1},
    New Integer() {2, 3},
    New Integer() {4, 5}
}

list.Add({6, 7})
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this GSerg. Although, I'm wondering on how do i do append the arr if the arr is empty (initial appending). For example, Dim arr(,). Then immediately followed by Append1DRow(arr, {6,7})

Comment: @John.Apple Check `If arr Is Nothing` in the `Append*` functions. If it is, redim `new_arr` to `(0,1)` and do not `Array.Copy`. If it's not, redim to the +1 dimension and copy as shown.